# How can I sync a Zune HD with Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, sync, zune, zune-hd

How can I sync/use a Zune HD with Mac OSX?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sync a Zune HD (but not older generations to my knowledge) with a Mac.  Microsoft has just enabled this ability with the [**Windows Phone 7 Connector for Mac**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/apps/mac-connector.aspx).

> Sync music, movies, TV shows, and podcasts from your existing Apple iTunes library to your Windows Phone or Zune HD